# Residues of even and odd functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that the residue at 0 and infinity is zero when f is an even complex function.

Now I do understand that since f is even, its Laurent series cannot have non zero 1/z terms, thus the residues will be zero... at all points? That's what I not sure about. Would that be enough for both the residue at 0 (which makes sense) and at infinity (with the following definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity )?

I have to show further that if f is odd, then the residue at a point $z_0$ is equal to the residue at $-z_0$ and is again zero. How come?

edit: I'm guessing $z_0$ denote a singularity here.

Any hint would appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An even function cannot have a nonzero residue at $0$ or at $\infty$. There is nothing to stop it from having residues at other points: consider
$$\frac{2}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1} $$ 
What is true is that the singularities of an even function are symmetric about $0$, and that the residue at $-z_0$ is $-\mathrm{res}\,(f;z_0)$. Simply put, the residue function of an even function is odd. And conversely, the residue function of an odd function is even.

Hint for the proof: if $f$ is odd, then putting $-z$ instead of $z$ into its Laurent series gives the Laurent series of $-f$. Hence, if the Laurent series of $f$ about $z_0$ contains $c/(z-z_0)$, then the Laurent series of $-f$ about $-z_0$ will contain $c/(-z-z_0)$. Deciphering this, you'll arrive at $\mathrm{res}\,(f;-z_0)=\mathrm{res}\,(f;z_0)$

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'm confused as to why Res(f,0) wouldn't be zero though. the Laurent expansion at z=0 would need to have a non zero 1/x term, but that would contradict the parity of f, since 1/(-x) =/= 1/(x).

Comment: @gorgy For an even function, res(f,0) must be 0. This is what my first sentence says. And this is a special case of res(f,-z)=-res(f,z), which holds for even f.